# Reverse backward text from a pdf file?

Tags: pdf, text, reverse

The texts looks like this "stnetnoc." only even the letters are facing the wrong direction. And the pages displayed its side at the bottom and the top.

I'm not familiar with pdf coding or manipulation libraries.

There's a post suggesting another user to use printer to print the file reverse and it'll reverse the orders for the printed files. Ordering of the pages isn't the problem in my case, and I want to avoid printing the entire document since it's quite massive.

Comment: "I'm not familiar with pdf coding or manipulation libraries" suggests you are not asking on the correct site.

Comment: Sounds like the text isn't added backwards but instead it is *mirrored*. Seems like you want to perform a transformation on your PDF (mirror it, rotate it,...). However, as @Jongware explains, StackOverflow is a forum where you can post *specific* coding problems. This is not a place to ask for recommendations about this or that PDF coding or manipulation library.

Answer (score 1):

The error is only reproductible with MacOS finder preview for PDF and it is related to variable fonts.
In my case it was with Mulish font https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Mulish.
I downloaded the `source.ttf` and included the non variable version to make it work properly.